# How can i figure out if my list has more even or odd numbers?

Tags: javascript, html

I have this simple table that displays 200 random numbers from 1-100. and would like to know if there are more even or more odd numbers every time i run the script.

```
<tr>
    <td>Amount</td>
    <td>Random number</td>
</tr>
<script>
      //my variables to solve the equation
// the equation to solve the problem
for (var amount = 1; amount <= 200; amount++) {
    RNG = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
//this writes down all the answers
    document.write("<tr><td>"+ amount +"</td>");

    document.write("<td>" + " " + RNG +"</td></tr>");
}
// where i would like to know if there are more even or odd number
////
</script>

</table>
```

Comment: Have you tried adding a counter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done by updating your code to something like this:

```
<script>
    // my variables to solve the equation
    // the equation to solve the problem
    evenCount = 0;
    oddCount  = 0;
    for (var amount = 1; amount <= 200; amount++) {
        RNG = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
        //this writes down all the answers
        document.write("<tr><td>"+ amount +"</td>");
        document.write("<td>" + " " + RNG +"</td></tr>");

        if (RNG % 2 !== 0) {
            oddCount++;
        }else {
            evenCount++;
        }
    }
    if (oddCount > evenCount) {
        alert ('Odd numbers are more than Even numbers')
    }
    // where i would like to know if there are more even or odd number
    ////
</script>
```